# Using "provide" to say "someone is provided to do something"

Tags: word-usage

> In addition, the user is provided to specify the context in which each rule is executed.

Is my usage of "provide" correct?

Comment: What are you trying to express here? What do you mean by this sentence?

Comment: Either 'able' or 'required' could be the correct word, depending on what is intended.

Comment: *provided to specify* does not make sense. Could you paraphrase what you are trying to say? Do you mean like *given the means* or *asked* instead of "provided"?

Comment: @user3169 given the means is close, I could say it *the user is provided with (a mean / a mechanism) to specify the context in which each rule is executed*, if it is correct

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the usage is correct, but you need to specify what is provided to the user.

> In addition, the user is provided [with what? specify what is provided to the user]to specify the context in which each rule is executed.